# How do I post this model in MVC 4 (null model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model, http-post, nul

My problem is quite common but I can't seem to figure out on my own why when I POST my model that it's null. My FormCollection seems to suggest it doesn't understand the whole model which it is POSTING. See code below:

**My model - CaseForm.cs**

```
namespace Models.CaseForm
{
    public class CaseForm
    {
        public CaseForm()
        {
            this.Person = new Person();
            this.Case = new Case();
            this.Cases = new List<Case>();
        }

        public string strMessage;
        public bool isValidModel;

        public Person Person = new Person();
        public Case Case = new Case();
        public List<Case> Cases = new List<Case>();
    }
}
```

**My view = NewCase.cshtml**

```
@model Models.CaseForm.CaseForm

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Raw(Model.strMessage)
    <br />

    @*@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.CaseId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.CaseNotes)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.CaseRef)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.FirstAppointmentMade)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.IsClosedRecord)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.IsFirstContact)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.PersonId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.ReasanForContact)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.WasAdvisedByEmail)*@

    <legend>
        <fieldset>
            <h4>New Case for @Html.Raw(Model.Person.Firstname + " " + Model.Person.Firstname)</h4>
        </fieldset>
    </legend>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Person.PersonRef)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Person.PersonRef)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Person.LesasPerson.ActionTakenPending, "Action Taken Pending")</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Person.LesasPerson.ActionTakenPending)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Person.LesasPerson.DateArrivedInUk, "Date Arrived In UK")</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Person.LesasPerson.DateArrivedInUk)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Person.LesasPerson.ImmigrationStatus, "Immigration Status")</td>
            @{
    string ImmigrationStatus = Model.Person.LesasPerson.ImmigrationStatus == null ? "No status set for this person" : Model.Person.LesasPerson.ImmigrationStatus;
            }

            <td>@Html.Raw(ImmigrationStatus)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br />

    <div id="divCase" style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; padding: 5px;">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><b>If Case ref is not known then leave blank for now.</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Case.CaseRef, "Case Reference code")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Case.CaseRef)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Case.FirstAppointmentMade, "First Appointment Made")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Case.FirstAppointmentMade)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Case.IsFirstContact, "Is First Contact")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Case.IsFirstContact)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Case.ReasanForContact, "Reason For Contact")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @{
    List<SelectListItem> Reasons = new List<SelectListItem>();
    Reasons.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "One Off Advice", Value = "One Off Advice", Selected = false });
    Reasons.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Housing", Value = "Housing", Selected = true });
    Reasons.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Immigration", Value = "Immigration", Selected = false });
    Reasons.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Social Advice", Value = "Social Advice", Selected = false });
    Reasons.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "Legal", Value = "Legal", Selected = false });

    Reasons = Reasons.OrderBy(r => r.Text).ToList();
                    }
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Case.ReasanForContact, Reasons)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Case.WasAdvisedByEmail, "Was Advised By Email")
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Case.WasAdvisedByEmail)
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr />
        <div id="divCaseNote" style="padding:10px;">
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Case.CaseNotes.Count; i++)
            {
                int status = i + 1;
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.Label("This is note: " + status.ToString())</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Case.CaseNotes[i].CaseStatus, "Write title or status for note")</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Case.CaseNotes[i].CaseStatus)</td>
                        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Case.CaseNotes[i].CaseStatus)</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Case.CaseNotes[i].CaseNote, "Case Note")</td>
                        <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Case.CaseNotes[i].CaseNote)</td>
                        <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Case.CaseNotes[i].CaseNote)</td>

                        @*@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.CaseNotes[i].CaseDate)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.CaseNotes[i].CaseId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.CaseNotes[i].CaseNote)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.CaseNotes[i].CaseNoteId)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.CaseNotes[i].CaseStatus)*@
                    </tr>
                </table>
            }
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Note For Case" name="btnSubmit" />
        <input type="submit" value="Remove Note For Case" name="btnSubmit" />
    </div>

    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Save Case To Database" name="btnSubmit" />
    <br />
    <b>@Html.ActionLink("Go back to people grid", "PeopleDashboard")</b>
}
```

**ActionResult NewCase (POST)**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult NewCase(string btnSubmit, FormCollection form, CaseForm Model)
        {
            RepositoryLesas RepositoryLesas = new RepositoryLesas();
            switch (btnSubmit)
            {
                case "Add Note For Case":
                    #region AddClaimStatus
                    Model.Case.CaseNotes.Add(new CaseNotes());
                    // SET to false as Model is not ready for DB
                    Model.isValidModel = false;
                    // SET message for the user
                    Model.strMessage = "Type new note information in the fields below";

                    return View("~/Views/Case/NewCase.cshtml", Model);
                    #endregion
                case "Remove Note For Case":
                    #region RemoveClaimStatus
                    // Can't remove IF only 1 
                    Model.isValidModel = false;
                    if (Model.Case.CaseNotes.Count == 0 || Model.Case.CaseNotes.Count == 1)
                    {
                        Model.strMessage = "Must be at least one case note before saving case";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Model.Case.CaseNotes.RemoveAt(Model.Case.CaseNotes.Count - 1);
                        Model.strMessage = "One case note removed.";
                    }
                    return View("~/Views/Case/NewCase.cshtml", Model);
                    #endregion
                //case "Save Case To Database":
                    //#region submit
                    //if (!Model.isValidModel)
                    //{
                    //    RepositoryLesas.InsertClaim(Model);
                    //    // Do one final check before going to success screen
                    //    Model.strMessage = "Claim data inserted into the database.";
                    //    Model.Person = RepositoryLesas.GetPerson(Model.Person.PersonID);
                    //    // Use to persist data through redirect - Model data will be lost otherwise
                    //    TempData["Model"] = Model;
                    //    return RedirectToAction("Success", new { URL = SuccessClaimUrl });
                    //}
                    //else
                    //{
                    //    Model.strMessage = "Claim data could not be inserted into the database. Missing key fields.";
                    //    return View("~/Views/Claim/AddClaim.cshtml", Model);
                    //}
                    //#endregion
            }
            return View("~/Views/Case/NewCase.cshtml", Model);
        }
```

**My FormCollection**

[image]

In my form collection, it only interprets the case object, it should show:

- strMessage
- isValidModel
- Case obj
- Cases collection
- Person obj

Why is this model not posting correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need getter and setter on your properties. The `DefaultModelBinder` creates a new instance of `CaseForm` but can set the values of its properties that have been posted back because they dont have setters.

```
public class CaseForm
{
  public string strMessage { get; set; }
  public bool isValidModel { get; set; }
  ....
  public List<Case> Cases { get; set; }
}
```

Note you do not need the parameter `FormCollection form`

Note also your are rendering hidden inputs for some properties

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Case.CaseRef)
```

and then creating a textbox for the same property

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Case.CaseRef)
```

You need to remove the `HiddenFor` because it will only bind the first value on post back (the value in the hidden input) and ignore the second (the value in the textbox)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise I forgot the get/set in my model for those objects.